# Spring data: MongoDB: Aggregation: group by nested object

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I'm working with MongoDB 3.2.2 and Spring Data 2.1.8. I have the following document model with dynamic `data` field:

```
@Data
@Accessors(chain = true)
@Document(collection = "someCollection")
public class SomeEntity implements Serializable {

    @Id
    String id;

    //some fields

    Map<String, Object> data;

}
```

My goal is grouping my documents by specific key from the `data` field. For example, i have the following db content:

```
{
  "_id": "5e5f8a89b70e4123a8285aa3",
  "data": {
    "someField": "someValue",
  }
},
{
  "_id": "5e5f72fcb70e4123a8285aa2",
  "data": {
    "someField": "someValue",
  }
},
{
  "_id": "5e5d22939ce87e2fccd80973",
  "data": {
    "someField": "otherValue",
  }
}
```

I'd like to build the grouping aggregation using Spring Data like the following query for MongoDB:

```
$group: {
  {
    _id: "$data.someField",
    count: {
      $sum: 1
    }
  }
}
```

And I'd like to receive the following result:

```
{
  _id: "someValue",
  count: 2
},
{
  _id: "otherValue",
  count: 1
}
```

For this goal i'm using the next grouping with `org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.Aggregation`:

```
Aggregation.group("$data.someField").count().as("count")
```

But i've got an error during execution of aggregation:

```
org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property someField found for type Object! Traversed path: SomeEntity.data.
```

What was wrong? Could someone help me, please?

P.S.: i've also tried to use $replaceRoot for `data` field, so i could group documents by `someField`, but it's newer db version (New in version 3.4)

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that you only have a little typo: `No property someFiled`?

Try the following:

```
group("$data.someField").count().as("count")
```

Comment: Thank you, but not. The typo is only in my post, not in real code. I've already fixed the post.